# chmod hard drive at grub?

Tags: grub2, chmod

A computer of a friend of mine used to have a command at GRUB that changed permissions for a hard drive to 666 or whatever so he could access it from a VM without worrying about groups &c. This friend passed away a few months ago and I can’t remember exactly what he had in his GRUB file. It may have involved having GRUB (or some other startup process) run a bash script that included something like `chmod -R 666 /dev/sdb`. What I distinctly remember is that, at the end of his GRUB file, he included some “wait” command (in seconds) to allow all start processes to complete *before* the chmod command worked.

Now I’m trying to have my PC work like his. Could anyone figure out more or less what he did?

Comment: I haven’t yet decided what permissions I’ll allow. I’ve been trying to emulate my friend’s system somehow, and one of the things I do know about it is that he had included two or three lines in his GRUB to achieve just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve managed to solve this through a different route. The aim was to make a `chmod` on a drive permanent. The solution is to add a line in the `/etc/rc.local` file, just before the last line ("exit 0"). The added line could be:

```
chmod 666 /dev/sdb -R
```

but I’ve opted for something less dramatic, which is to change user ownership of the drive:

```
chown -R [username] /dev/sdb
```

This may pose other problems down the line, but so far so good.

Comment: You don't need `-R`, since the device file is, well, a file, and not a directory.